# 1985 IMO Problem 1 solution by extending

Tags: geometry, contest-math, euclidean-geometry, circles, quadrilateral

> A circle has center on the side $AB$ of the cyclic quadrilateral $ABCD$. The other three sides are tangent to the circle. Prove that $AD+BC=AB$.

There are a lot of solution available on [Artofproblemsolving](https://artofproblemsolving.com/wiki/index.php/1985_IMO_Problems/Problem_1)

But could someone give me a solution by extending $AD$ and $BC$? This is what I do when I tried to solve this problem, unfortunately I didn't reach my goal there. Here is what I could find:
I let $K$ be the intersection of $AD$ and $BC$.
Since $ABCD$ is cyclic we could get that $\angle{KDC}=\angle{CBA}=x$ and $\angle{KCD}=\angle{DAB}=y$. If I were able to find that $2x+y=180°$ then I'd be able to prove that $\triangle{KBA}$ is an isosceles triangle and $KB=AB$ and lastly prove that $KC=AD$ and we're done. But I'm stuck at finding $2x+y=180°$. Please help

Answer (score 2):

Solution 7.

Let $O$ be a center of the circle, which tangent to the sides $AD,$ $DC$ and $BC$ and

let $E\in AB$ such that $AD=AE.$

Thus, it's enough to prove that $EB=BC$.

We can assume that $E$ is placed between $O$ and $B$.

Also, let $\measuredangle ADO=\measuredangle ODC=\alpha$ and $\measuredangle DCO=\measuredangle OCB=\beta.$

Thus, $$\measuredangle DEA=\frac{1}{2}(180^{\circ}-\measuredangle DAB)=\frac{1}{2}(180^{\circ}-(180^{\circ}-2\beta))=\beta=\measuredangle DCO,$$
which says that $DOEC$ is cyclic, which says:
$$\measuredangle CEB=\measuredangle ODC=\alpha,$$
which since $\measuredangle EBC=180^{\circ}-2\alpha,$ gives $$\measuredangle ECB=\alpha,$$ $$EB=BC$$ and we are done!